# What may cause IIS 7 to restart automatically

Tags: iis-7, configuration

I'm trying to stop IIS 7 'Windows Process Activation Service' from within my application. It also stops a dependency - 'World Wide Web Publishing Service'. The dependency stops always but the main service doesn't. I think that it restarts automatically because I don't get any errors in my application. The question is what may cause IIS to restart automatically or prevent it from stopping?

p.s. I'm not doing any other things related to configuration, just stopping the service through the `ServiceController` object

**Edit:**

The startup type of the main service is `manual` and `automatic` for dependency. I also have such settings in service properties ->recovery->failure 1,2,3 run a program, iisreset.exe as a program to run. Anyway I didn't get any error in my application, but if it could restart due to some errors I'd like to know how to check that.

I should have mentioned also that it doesn't happen all the time, in most cases it stops, but sometimes it doesn't, I can't event get any pattern or relation to something

Comment: What Startup Type do you have WPAS service configured as? Is it manual or automatic? I tried doing the same thing using ServiceController object via PowerShell and it stops the service just fine.

Comment: @LukeP I've updated my question

Comment: Why stop it at all? If you're not going to use IIS, why not just not install it
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows Process Activation Service` is not the main IIS service, `World Wide Web Publishing Service` is.

Pay no attention to the process activation service's state, and don't mess with it manually; it's just gonna do its own thing (which is why it's set to manual startup).

Comment: I agree with the service doing it's own thing. I'm still curious though why it doesn't stay stopped. On my test environment I'm able to run:  (new-Object System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController('WAS','localhost')).Stop() and it stays stopped.

Comment: @LukeP It's involved in worker process management - it's started dynamically when needed, and won't start if IIS is just sitting idle.

Comment: Which makes sense and is exactly what I see here. But, the OP asked why it doesn't stay switched off. I agree with you though. It's not something you should have to worry about.

Comment: "don't mess with it manually" - after a few days figuring out what's the problem is, this is the only reasonable solution I see